# Group By, IFNULL and Order By date

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by, ifnull

I have to take the rows of my table grouped by types, if they are not null, and user. Order them by time. But the grouping must be separated...

This is my table:

| id | event_code | user | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:59:00 |
| 9 | null | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:56:00 |
| 8 | null | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:54:00 |
| 7 | A | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:53:00 |
| 6 | A | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:52:00 |
| 5 | null | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:51:00 |
| 4 | null | 4 | 2021-10-20 09:50:00 |
| 3 | B | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:49:00 |
| 2 | B | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:48:00 |
| 1 | B | 12 | 2021-10-20 09:43:00 |

i want to get this:

| id | event_code | user | time | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:55:00 | 1 |
| 9 | null | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:54:00 | 1 |
| 8 | null | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:54:00 | 1 |
| 7,6 | A | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:53:00 | 2 |
| 5 | null | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:51:00 | 1 |
| 4 | null | 4 | 2021-10-20 09:50:00 | 1 |
| 3,2 | B | 6 | 2021-10-20 09:49:00 | 2 |
| 1 | B | 12 | 2021-10-20 09:43:00 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

I have found this solution:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id),event_code,user,time FROM(
SELECT 
 id,event_code,user,time,
if(@a = event_code, @b, @b := @b + 1) as grouping_col,
@a := event_code
FROM testing
JOIN (select @a := 1, @b := 0) as temp
  ) as t
GROUP BY grouping_col,user
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abfcd4/17

But, how I order the grouped rows by time?
**I will have 7,6** but i have 6,7.

Answer (score 1):

@gasmor to keep the order you should include the order statement in the group_concat clause more on :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat, like:

```
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id order by `time` desc),event_code,user,time 
FROM ( SELECT 
              id,
              event_code,
              `user`,
              `time`,
               if(@a = event_code, @b, @b := @b + 1) as grouping_col,
               @a := event_code
       FROM testing
JOIN ( 
      select @a := 1, @b := 0) as temp
      ) as t
GROUP BY grouping_col,user ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vhqJXYFy52xRtVBc97R1EL/4

You should keep in mind, when you use group by:

> The selected columns should be part of the group by or part of an
> aggregation function like `SUMN()`, `MAX()`...